# ANSI escape sequence "\033[1m" printing bold for rest of program instead of specified line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the ANSI escape sequence for bold text;`"\033[1m"` in a print statement to create a bold header for my Python project. The problem is once I write a line like this: `print("\033[1m"+"title")`, any normal print statement I write afterword returns in bold as well. How can I make just one specified line bold instead of everything? Code:

```
print("\033[1m"+"Title")
print("Why is this text in bold as well?")
```

Comment: reset when you no longer want to have bold. Some of the convenient libraries allow for auto-reset.

Comment: `print("\033[1m"+"Title"+"\033[0m")` instead

Comment: You need to print `\033[22m` to reset the bold escape sequence.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, any code we type into this prompt will also be colored **bold**, as will any subsequent output! That is how Ansi colors work: once you print out the special code enabling a color, the color persists forever until someone else prints out the code for a different color, or prints out the **Reset** code to disable it.

We can disable it by printing the **Reset** code above:

```
print("\033[1m"+"Title"+"\033[0m")
```

[See here](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to end the escape sequence. Using `\033[0m` will reset all formatting.

```
print("\033[1m"+"Title"+"\033[0m")
```

Comment: Note that `\033[0m` will reset all formatting, while `\033[22m` will just reset the bold.